# Python Break Statement to end calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, break

I keep getting the error "break is outside of loop" I've read a lot and I'm clearly missing something.

```
again = input(" again? y/n")

if again == "y" or \
again == "Y":
main()

else:
print("Thanks for using my calculator!")

again = input("Would you like to calculate again? y/n")

if again == "y" or \
again == "Y":
main()
else:
print("Thanks!")
#BREAK !!!!????
main()
```

Comment: Is that your actual indentation?

Comment: no, it needed to get formatted to post

Comment: the whole function is inside the loop?

Comment: There is no loop. What is `main()`? What do you want "break" to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(True):
    again = input("Would you like to calculate again? y/n")

    if again == "y" or again == "Y":
        main()
    else:
        print("Thanks!")
        break
```

Try to use "break" in lower case. And, try to put it inside a loop. Please mark my answer if right. The "main" can have loop inside but that is independent of the while loop that I specified at the top.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be coming from C++ where main and break are used. See if this helps. Note, calling a function has to be below/after you have defined it, if you are running python in interactive mode.

```py
# Functions

def main():
    print("Start calculator")

def myfunc(again):
    if again in ("y", "Y"): 
        main()  # call your calculator  
    else:
        print("Thanks!")

# Run tests 

print("Starting Test: 'y'. \n ")
again = 'y'  # Set again to 'y'
myfunc(again)  # Expect 'Start calculator' output

print("Starting Test: 'Y'. \n ")
again = 'Y'  # Set again to 'Y' capital
myfunc(again)  # Expect 'Start calculator' output

print("Starting Test: 'n'. \n ")
again = 'n'  # Set input to 'n'
myfunc(again)  # Expect 'Thanks!' output

print("Starting Test: 'error'. \n ")
again = 'error'  # Set input to a random string
myfunc(again)  # Expect 'Thanks!' output
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a much simpler code would be something like this...

```
#set value of again to y. then go into the loop
#again.lower() will convert to lowercase allowing you to check against 'y'

again = 'y'

while again.lower() == 'y' :
    main() #this will call main only if again is y

    again = input("Would you like to calculate again? y/n")

print("Thanks!") #print thanks after you exit the loop
```